# Cannot Launch firefox using selenium on AWS EC2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2 uses ubuntu 64bit.
cannot start firefox using selenium

Below is the source code

```
async def submit_form(request: Request, keyword: str = Form(...), url: str = Form(...), number: int = Form(...),suburl: str = Form(...)):
  LinkLists = ["tel", "nav.cx", "lin.ee", "circlebiz.info"]
  logger.debug("Starting form submission")
  for _ in range(number):
    options = Options()
    # ここをあなたのシステムのFirefoxのパスに置き換えてください
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/ubuntu/selenium/geckodriver', options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.jp/")
    search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
    search.send_keys(keyword)
    search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.g")))
    links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
```

The error is below

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

Which firefox results in below
/usr/bin/firefox

I put geckodriver compatible with firefox113.